# Shortest way to initialize a new list from an existing collection (C#)?

Tags: c#, list, lambda, initialization, enumeration

How can I do the following in C# with less lines of code? I'm just initializing a new list using the fields of elements in an existing collection, but modifying each field before I add it to the list.

```
            List<string> itemDescriptions = new List<string>();
            foreach (CoolItem item in _coolItems)
            {
                itemDescriptions.Add("* " + item.Description);
            }
```

I'm guessing lambda expressions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the LINQ Expression for this :

```
var itemDescriptions = 
    _coolItems.Select(item => "* " + item.Description).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var itemDescriptions = _someItemCollection.ConvertAll(item => "* " + item.ShortDescription);
```

Comment: there is no need to ConvertAll, a simple Select will work better.

Comment: ConvertAll() is only for List<T> not for any collection.

Comment: @Farzin, you have to call ToList() at the end. @manojlds, yepp I kinda skipped that part...

Comment: Interestingly enough I did a small benchmark and on my machine the `ConvertAll` was on average 20% faster than the `Select`.

Comment: It would have been a surprise if it weren't faster. Select has to instantiate an iterator with its state machine-based MoveNext(). That iterator is then read til the end to build a new List<T>. Whereas ConvertAll can create this new list using the exact size (no copying while growing) and otherwise it has just the cost of the lambda plus assigning the result to the appropriate index. However, this is me sitting on my MacBook, not able to check it in Reflector. So I could end up being wrong about its implementation after all. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 List<string> itemDescriptions = (from item in _coolItems
                                  select "* " + item.Descirption).ToList();
```

Edit:

ConvertAll() wont work for any collection. It is only for List

Comment: Personally I prefer using the extension method syntax when you're only doing a single select or where - the extra bits of query expression syntax just add fluff here.

Answer (score -1):

var fileNames = _coolItems.Select(p => (p.Description));